# Using Elastic Search Filters in Grafana Alert Labels

Tags: grafana

I have configured Elastic Data Source for Grafana, and I am filtering out error count in logs  kubernetes deployment. It works as expected except the labels in message template.

I want to print the value for kubernetes.deployment.name which I get from the elastic datasource.
It is showed in labels as follows

```
[ var='A' labels={kubernetes.deployment.name=api-controller} value=271 ], [ var='B' labels={kubernetes.deployment.name=api-controller} value=0 ]
```

But when I print it in the description it gives me

Following is the error message I am printing

Error Count for {{ $labels.kubernetes.deployment.name  }} has crossed the threshold of 5000 errors in 15 minutes

```
Error Count for <no value> has crossed the threshold of 5000 errors in 15 minutes
```

Another way I tried was

{{ $labels["kubernetes.deployment.name"] }}

But it prints the whole expression as it is.

```
Error Count for {{ $labels["kubernetes.deployment.name"] }} has crossed the threshold of 5000 errors in 15 minutes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use:

```
{{ index $labels "kubernetes.deployment.name" }}
```